# For How long next link will remain active for Microsoft Office 365 Calendar Sync

Tags: office365

I want to sync my PHP based calendar with office365 using following url to track changes

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarView/delta?startdatetime=2020-01-01T00%3a00%3a00Z&enddatetime=2020-08-04T00%3a00%3a00Z

Now this URL will either return me next link or delta link, my problem is I don't want to sync more than 50 events at a time, so can I store **next link** in my database if there is no **delta link** in my request response or there is a certain time limit on next link expiry?